# Fresh new Centos on Oracle VM Virtualbox: Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos, virtualization, windows-11

New Windows11 setup with Oracle VM Virtualbox 6.1, trying to install first VM using CentOS Stream9 iso. During iso boot system crashes: `Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception`. I thought there was something wrong with virtualization settings, so I tried to check those:
In BIOS of the host enabled those:

- Hyperthreading
- VTx
- VTx for Directed I/O (VTd)

In Windows Features I have disabled Hyper-V and underlying Hyper-V Management Tools, Hyper-V platform.

I noticed that on another PC I have `Execution engine: VT-x/AMD-V` whilst on the new PC it uses `Native API` (aka turtle mode), also `Nested Paging` and `Unrestricted Execution` are inactive.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Try making a new, different virtual machine to see if that works. I am using VMware on Windows 11 and Hardware Virtualization is enabled in BIOS. Linux VMs work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Cause: Windows Device Guard protects against virtualization-related attacks or something like that. Unfortunately idk how to allow a particular app to work under Device Guard, but here is how to disable it:

- run `GPEDIT.MSC`
- go to computer configuration \administrative templates \system\ device guard
- right click on "turn on virtualization-based security", choose "edit", then  "disabled"
- click "apply", then "ok" and close  group policy editor
- type `GPUPDATE /FORCE` in cmd  and hit Enter
- wait until complete then reboot windows.

[source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-disable-device-guard/5f29388b-b59b-44cb-ae16-7f60aee2a449)